# What is a region of type 3 with regards to Green's Theorem?

Tags: greens-theorem

I understand that a region of type 1 is where two curves are connected by two vertical lines and that a region of type 2 is where two curves are connected by two horizontal lines. But what is a region of type 3?

Answer (score -1):

A region of type III is both type I and type II.

Comment: So would that be a rectangle with four straight edges? Or a blob with four curves? Or are they both regions of type 3?

Comment: A rectangle is definitely a type III region but not all type III regions are rectangles. A blob with four curves as you've described could be considered a type III region if it is closed and contained in some ellipse.

Comment: @TSF I do not understand why the blob you describe is a type III region. In this context a type I region is of the form $D = \{(x,y)|a\leq x \leq b, g_1(x)\leq y \leq g_2(x) \}$ and similar for II but in y. Could you expand on in what sense the blob is both type I and type II?

Comment: It means it consists of four curves but they are not constrained to be straight lines.